# Filter linq query results using values from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to filter my query results `jobs`. I am using the passed List parameter `types` trying to filter `jobs`. The `types` comes from Multiple check boxes that are selected. The issue is I am getting wrong Jobs results here `foreach (var type in types)`. I only get the results of the last item in the `foreach`.

```
public JobsOutPut GetJobs(List<string> types, string country)
{
    //Getting the jobs here
    var jobs =
    (
        from row in _jobCategoryRepository.GetAll().ToList()
        join rowT in _jobTypeRepository.GetAll().ToList()
        on row.JobId equals rowT.JobId
        orderby row.CreationTime descending
        select new JobDto
        {
            Id = row.JobId,
            Title = row.Job.Title,
        }
    )
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(j => j.Country.Contains(country));

    if (types.Any())//if that List has stuff filter jobs using those values.
    {
        //is there a better approach leading to correct results?I ran out of ideas 
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            jobs = jobs.Where(j => j.TypeName == type);

        }
    }

    var fJobs = jobs.ToList();
    return new FilterJobOutPut
    {
        JobsList = fJobs,
    };
}
```

Comment: I believe `if (types.Any())` isn't really required here, because all you have there is a `foreach` loop, and `foreach` will execute only if there is at least one record.

Comment: `foreach (var type in types)
                        {
                            jobs=jobs.Where(j => j.TypeName == type);

                        }` Logically it is hard to make sense of that code. Let's say types contained 'A', 'B' and 'C'. It looks like you are trying to generate a WHERE clase saying `WHERE TypeName = 'A' AND TypeName = 'B' AND TypeName = 'C'` (which is clearly pointless - all three conditions can't be true). Is that correct?

Comment: @AD8 that Any() I need it to check if there is something there. because if I dont, then program will always go into that foreach and thats not what I want

Comment: @AneleNgqandu Even if program tries to execute `foreach`, it won't effectively do anything since the collections will be empty anyway. It is completely safe to get rid of that.

Comment: @mjwills Yes Sir, the logic is to search the jobs using the type in the foreach WHERE TypeName='A' AND 'B' AND 'C' so on...

Comment: @mjwills its AND

Comment: You want OR instead of AND  @AneleNgqandu - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want this:

```
public JobsOutPut GetJobs(List<string> types, string country)
{
    //Getting the jobs here
    var jobs =
    (
        from row in _jobCategoryRepository.GetAll().ToList()
        join rowT in _jobTypeRepository.GetAll().ToList() on row.JobId equals rowT.JobId
        let jobDto = new JobDto
        {
            Id = row.JobId,
            Title = row.Job.Title,
        }
        where jobDto.Country.Contains(country)
        where !types.Any() || types.Any(t => jobDto.TypeName == t)
        orderby row.CreationTime descending
        select jobDto
    );

    return new FilterJobOutPut
    {
        JobsList = jobs.ToList(),
    };
}
```

Or if you want to get more fancy, this:

```
public JobsOutPut GetJobs(List<string> types, string country) =>
    new FilterJobOutPut
    {
        JobsList =
        (
            from row in _jobCategoryRepository.GetAll().ToList()
            join rowT in _jobTypeRepository.GetAll().ToList() on row.JobId equals rowT.JobId
            let jobDto = new JobDto
            {
                Id = row.JobId,
                Title = row.Job.Title,
            }
            where jobDto.Country.Contains(country)
            where !types.Any() || types.Any(t => jobDto.TypeName == t)
            orderby row.CreationTime descending
            select jobDto
        ).ToList()
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Contains()` to make your code more simple,just make sure case of `j.TypeName` && contents of `types` should be same

```
if (types.count >0)
{
      return new FilterJobOutPut
      {
        JobsList = jobs.Where(j => types.Contains(j.TypeName)).ToList()
      };
}
else
    return null //make null check where ever you call this method else use new FilterJobOutPut()
```